# Using bash to parse a log for unique MAC addresses

Tags: linux, bash

I've got Debian box set up as a syslog server for a couple cisco ASAs. They are running DHCP and I'm attemping to track the unique instances of a MAC addresses being assigned a lease. I've set the ASAs to only log the message that the cisco DHCPd uses, and it sends that to the Debian server as %HOSTIPADDRESS%.log, which then rotates out daily. So I've got a directory that is filled with this:

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     536351 Aug 23 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.10
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     459634 Aug 22 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.11
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     176957 Aug 21 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.12
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     246654 Aug 20 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.13
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     459978 Aug 19 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.14
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     606987 Aug 18 06:21 10.10.10.4.log.15
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     599140 Aug 17 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.16
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     605837 Aug 16 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.17
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     607630 Aug 15 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.18
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     189493 Aug 14 06:24 10.10.10.4.log.19
```

In each of those logs I've got something that looks like this:

```
Aug 23 06:20:19 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 011c.9148.dbb4.15 (172.16.1.196)
Aug 23 06:20:41 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 0138.0f4a.986a.16 (172.16.1.126)
Aug 23 06:20:51 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 0190.b686.63c6.a9 (172.16.1.193)
Aug 23 06:20:55 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 0154.4e90.8a7a.00 (172.16.1.211)
Aug 23 06:21:11 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 012c.0e3d.fcf6.34 (172.16.1.189)
Aug 23 06:21:35 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 0154.4e90.8a7a.00 (172.16.1.211)
Aug 23 06:21:51 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 0154.4e90.8a7a.00 (172.16.1.211)
Aug 23 06:22:29 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 5caf.0664.cd18 (172.16.1.212)
Aug 23 06:24:00 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 01fc.dbb3.49af.eb (172.16.1.207)
Aug 23 06:24:21 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 01a0.3be3.03b4.74 (172.16.1.195)
Aug 23 06:24:39 10.10.10.4 %ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface inside:  address granted 01b4.79a7.1895.33 (172.16.1.157)
```

The problem, is that dhcp leases renew,as you can see by the multiple instances of the same device at 172.16.1.211, for instance. I thought I could get around this by setting longer leases, as my understanding of how DHCP works is that leases would not start the renewal process until they reached their half-life but that is not working.

I'm also running into issues of address pool depletion because my leases are so long, and the ASA model I'm using has a hard limit to the size of it's scope.

Long story short, I need to parse those logs and retrieve the number of unique MAC addresses that occur in one of those logs. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished with bash? If I knew how to pull that info from one of the files, I could get through setting up  process to do it for all of them using cron or something. I am not a programmer, however, I'm a network engineer. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `awk '{print $12}' file1 file2 ... | uniq -c` ? If this doesn't answer it, please improve your Q by showing the required output given your sample inputs. (Please do this in the body of your Q, and not as a comment). Good luck.

Comment: This works for me. I want to mark this as an answer, but I can't seem to (maybe because it's a comment?) Not sure what to do protocol-wise, but this will definitely do  the trick. Thanks.

Comment: OK, let me know if you need any further clarifications. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Long story short, I need to parse those logs and retrieve the number of unique MAC addresses that occur in one of those logs.

Yes, given the regular nature of the data in your log files, this is very easy to do with several different tools.

The most basic would be to use `cut`

```
cut -d" " -f13 | sort | uniq -c
```

A more advanced tool is `awk`, and it provides many logic enhancments that allow you to add as many conditional statements as you want to filter the data as needed. For your case, though it is still very simple,

```
awk '{print $12}' | sort | uniq -c
```

In both cases, `cut` and `awk`, I only had to count over the number of fields in  your data to the value of interest, and then specify that as the column (field number in `awk`-speak).

(when testing these answers, I found that using cut required using `-d" "` and `-f13` (for some reason). I thought `cut` defaulted to `-d" "` but I had to specify it explicitly for the code to work).

Of course in both examples, I'm using the `sort` and `uniq` utilities, (`man uniq` for the how-to). `uniq`, has several options, and the `-c` option indicates `count`, so the data needs to be sorted for the counts to accumulate correctly (I missed that in my original comment).

---

Just for example, you could extend your counter to filter by the date value at the front of each record with

```
awk '/^Aug 23/{print $12}' | sort | uniq -c
```

But there are many more filtering and logic tools that you can use with `awk`.

---

If you're going to be working with logfile data regularly (or other non-XML-like data), I'd recommend working thru the [Grymoire's Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) .

IHTH